# $a,b\in\mathbb Z^+$, and the equations given are $a-b=120$, and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=105\gcd(a,b)$. What is $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> $a,b\in\mathbb Z^+$, and the equations given are $a-b=120$, and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=105\gcd(a,b)$. What is $a$?

So what I did was that I first found that $a=b+120$, and plugged that value of $a$ into the second equation:$$\begin{align}\operatorname{lcm}(120+b,b)&=105\gcd(120+b,b)\\\frac{ab}{\gcd(120+b,b)}&=105\gcd(120+b,b)\\\gcd(120+b,b)^2&=\frac{ab}{105}\\\gcd(120+b,b)&=\sqrt{\frac{ab}{105}}\\\gcd(120,b)&=\sqrt{\frac{b(b+120)}{105}}\end{align}$$I'm not too sure if this is the correct way to go. Should I manipulate the equations, or should I do something else?

Comment: If you use `\text{lcm}` rather than `\operatorname{lcm}` then when you type `3\text{lcm}(a,b)` you'll see $3\text{lcm}(a,b)$ instead of $3\operatorname{lcm}(a,b).$ And it's not just that some horizontal space is added; rather the amount of space depends on the context. $$\begin{align} & 3\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) \\ & 3\text{lcm}(a,b) \end{align} $$

Comment: As in the dupe, cancelling $\gcd(a,b)$ reduces to the coprime case, where we need only find factors of $105$ satisfying the other condition (here: their difference divides $120$), and there  are only finitely many (few) possible divisors to check. As explained there, this **homogeneous** reduction is a commonly used technique to simplify such problems so you should be sure to master it (see links there for more examples)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=dx$ and $b=dy,$ where $d=\gcd(a,b).$

Thus, $$ab=105d^2$$ or
$$xy=105=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7.$$
Also, $$d(x-y)=120,$$ which says that $120$ is divisible by $x-y$.

Can you end it now?

I got $(x,y)=(15,7)$ is valid.